# why is this giving me 0,0 when i incremented the variable

Tags: python, logic

i tried to increment the variables a and b so when i type them in and press enter then the
variables a and b increase by one. My aim was that when i was done and wanted a and
printed i would type anything other than a and b and get the value of the variables. Hence,
i wrote the following code:

```
def increment():
    a = 0
    b = 0
    c = 0
    d = 0
    e = 0
    f = 0
    g = 0
    h = 0
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0
    l = 0
    m = 0
    n = 0
    o = 0
    p = 0
    q = 0
    r = 0
    s = 0
    t = 0
    u = 0
    v = 0
    w = 0
    x = 0
    y = 0
    z = 0

    statAsk = input("Enter your letter, else type go for overall statistics ")
    if statAsk == "a":
        a = a+1
        increment()
    elif statAsk == "b":
        b = b+1
        increment()
   else:
       print(a,b)

increment()
```

However when i ran this i a and b were not incremented at all and i got this:

```
Enter your letter, else type go for overall statistics a
Enter your letter, else type go for overall statistics b
Enter your letter, else type go for overall statistics b
Enter your letter, else type go for overall statistics a
Enter your letter, else type go for overall statistics b
Enter your letter, else type go for overall statistics go
0 0
```

How can i fix this logic error?

Comment: Everytime you run `increment` (recusively or not), your local `a,b,c,...` variables are set to zero. You would need global variables or another data or program structure to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the function only local variables are updated, global ones are not touched.

So to change global variables, use `global variable_name` before changing like:

```
if statAsk == "a":
        global a
        a = a+1
        increment()
```

And so on...

Answer (score 0):

Use python global keyword, your values are being reset to zero, every time you call the function. So declare your variables outside the function, your *increment()* function should be just,

```
def increment():
   

    statAsk = input("Enter your letter, else type go for overall statistics ")
    if statAsk == "a":
        a = a+1
        increment()
    elif statAsk == "b":
        b = b+1
        increment()
    else:
        print(a,b)

increment()
```

For more information on global keyword, you can refer:
[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_global_variables.asp)

This is just one of the many

Answer (score 0):

As @schwobaseggl has stated, the variables a,b,c,...,z that you are incrementing are local to that function. These variables only exist during the execution of that function. When you leave the increment function, these variables are destroyed.

But when you next call your increment function, you are again defining the local variables. Every single time you run this function, you are resetting the values. This is seen in your increment function when you are setting a = 0, b = 0 etc.

What you want to do is have those values persist. This can be done by defining the values outside of functions, where any variables defined here would have a global scope.

```
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0

#In order to access these variables above from inside a function, we can use the global keyword

def increment():
    ##Now we need to be able to access the global scope from this local scope (that is the scope of the function
    ##This global keyword means that we are accessing the variable a defined int eh global scope
    global a
    ##Run your logic
    if condition is met:
        a = a+1
```

I would avoid using the global keyword, and just pass variables as arguments through the increment function

Here's more about scopes in python https://www.w3schools.com/PYTHON/python_scope.asp

Answer (score 0):

You use a recursive approach. Then the function you recurse should always return the values. The returned values should be added to the results you already have.

```
def increment():
    a = 0
    b = 0
    c = 0
    d = 0
    e = 0
    f = 0
    g = 0
    h = 0
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0
    l = 0
    m = 0
    n = 0
    o = 0
    p = 0
    q = 0
    r = 0
    s = 0
    t = 0
    u = 0
    v = 0
    w = 0
    x = 0
    y = 0
    z = 0

    statAsk = input("Enter your letter, else type go for overall statistics ")
    if statAsk == "a":
        a += 1
        a_result, b_result = increment()
        a += a_result
        b += b_result
    elif statAsk == "b":
        b += 1
        a_result, b_result = increment()
        a += a_result
        b += b_result

    return a, b


a_result, b_result = increment()

print(a_result, b_result)
```

Result

```
Enter your letter, else type go for overall statistics a
Enter your letter, else type go for overall statistics a
Enter your letter, else type go for overall statistics b
Enter your letter, else type go for overall statistics go
2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def increment():
a = 0
b = 0
statAsk=''
while(statAsk !='x'): # Exit the program if you write
    statAsk = input("Enter your letter, else type go for overall ")
    if statAsk == "a":
         a+=1
    elif statAsk == "b":
         b+=1
return a ,b
```